# How to create table relationships in office js?

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js, excel-addins

I am creating an excel js add-on, but I cannot find a way to relate tables with their respective primary and secondary keys.
I need your help

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Andres, This is a known gap, we are thinking about providing a cell metadata API to unblock this scenario. you may also submit your request in uservoice and upvote for this feature at https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback?category_id=163563. and upvote for this feature. therefore we could make the right prioritization based on it. thanks for your support